# How to handle a JSON returned by Trello API in JS

Tags: json, api, parsing, trello

So I'm working on a simple .html file .

I'm making the query:

```
var toDo= Trello.get('/lists/5d3ef8543a911e79f63df8c0/cards');
```

And I'm calling:

```
console.log(toDo);
```

And I'm getting this weird JSON
[JSON returned by Trello API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNMii.png)

So my problem is that I need to acces the **responseJSON** atributte, and I dont know ho to do it.

I already tried with **toDo.responseJSON** but it returns **'undefined'**

**How can I handle this type of JSON?**

**How can I access the atributes shown on the image?**

Comment: What you are getting in your toDo variable is actually a Promise.

Comment: thanks @AlvaroFlañoLarrondo for the answer, do you know how can I handle this promise?. what I need is to acces the data inside **responseJSON**

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic example on how to handle the Promise:

```
Trello.get('/lists/5d3ef8543a911e79f63df8c0/cards')
.then(
    (success) => {
        console.log(success);
    }
).catch(
    (error) => {
        console.log(error);
    }
);
```